# Is there a way to show constraint message

Tags: spring-restdocs

I have class CategoryDTO  and i want to show the message "Description can't be null" in rest docs instead of "Must not be null".Though i know i can change this message my creating a constraint properties file and adding below line to it

```
javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.description=Must not be blank or null
```

But i want to show the message in NotNull annotation

```
public class CategoryDTO 
{
    private String id;

    @NotNull(message = "Description can't be null")
    @Size(min = 2 , max=30 , message = "Size must be greater than 2 and less than 30")
    private String description;
}
```

> Edit:

```
   @Test
    void testFindAll() 
    {

        CategoryDTO fruits = new CategoryDTO();
        fruits.setDescription("Fruits");
        fruits.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());


        CategoryDTO Nuts = new CategoryDTO();
        Nuts.setDescription("Nuts");
        Nuts.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

        ConstrainedFields fields = new ConstrainedFields(CategoryDTO.class);

        BDDMockito.when(categoryService.findAll()).thenReturn(Flux.just(fruits,Nuts));

        webTestClient.get().uri(CategoryController.rootURL + "/categories")
        .exchange().expectBodyList(CategoryDTO.class).
        hasSize(2).consumeWith(WebTestClientRestDocumentationWrapper.document("v1/get-all-categories",              
                responseFields(
                        fields.withPath("[]").description("An array of categories"),
                        fields.withPath("[].id").description("Id of category"),
                        fields.withPath("[].description").description("Description of category")
                        )
                ));
    }
```

Comment: Have you read the [section in the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/2.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html5/#documenting-your-api-constraints) on documenting constraints?

Comment: Yes i was following the same example, I have updated my question, is this the default functionality that instead of showing the message in constraint annotation its showing default messages  e.g for size its showing Size must be between 2 and 30 inclusive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, REST Docs' `ConstraintDescriptions` uses a `ResourceBundleConstraintDescriptionResolver` to obtain a description for each constraint. As its name suggests, it uses a `ResourceBundle` to provide the descriptions. You can provide your own implementation of `ConstraintDescriptionResolver` to use a different mechanism. In your case, you want to use the `message` from the constraint annotation as shown in the following example:

```
ConstraintDescriptions descriptions = new ConstraintDescriptions(CategoryDTO.class, (constraint) -> {
    return (String) constraint.getConfiguration().get("message");
});
List<String> descriptionProperty = descriptions.descriptionsForProperty("description");
System.out.println(descriptionProperty);
```

When executed, the above will output the following:

```
[Description can't be null, Size must be greater than 2 and less than 30]
```

If you don't always configure the `message` attribute, you may want to fall back to the resource bundle resolver, as shown in the following example:

```
ResourceBundleConstraintDescriptionResolver fallback = new ResourceBundleConstraintDescriptionResolver();
ConstraintDescriptions descriptions = new ConstraintDescriptions(CategoryDTO.class, (constraint) -> {
    String message = (String) constraint.getConfiguration().get("message");
    if (message != null) {
        return message;
    }
    return fallback.resolveDescription(constraint);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer i have also added the check weather its picking up default value i.e {javax.validation.constraints.Size.message}

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Andy's answer here is the final outcome

```
import static org.springframework.restdocs.payload.PayloadDocumentation.fieldWithPath;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.Attributes.key;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.springframework.restdocs.constraints.ConstraintDescriptions;
import org.springframework.restdocs.constraints.ResourceBundleConstraintDescriptionResolver;
import org.springframework.restdocs.payload.FieldDescriptor;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

public class ConstrainedFields
{
    private final ConstraintDescriptions constraintDescriptions;

    public ConstrainedFields(Class<?> input) {

        ResourceBundleConstraintDescriptionResolver fallback = new ResourceBundleConstraintDescriptionResolver();
        this.constraintDescriptions = new ConstraintDescriptions(input, (constraint) -> {
            String message = (String) constraint.getConfiguration().get("message");
            if (message != null && !Pattern.compile("\\{(.*?)\\}").matcher(message).matches()) {
                return message;
            }
            return fallback.resolveDescription(constraint);
        });     
    }

    public FieldDescriptor withPath(String path) 
    {
        return fieldWithPath(path).attributes(key("constraints").value(StringUtils
                .collectionToDelimitedString(constraintDescriptions
                        .descriptionsForProperty(path), ". ")));
    }
}
```